# Alamofire custom header not working

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm attempting to add a custom header to an `Alamofire` request but I don't think the header is being recognized. I still receive the same results and am now getting an `App Transport security` error. I'm adding a header specified here-> http://developer.dribbble.com/v1/media/#comment-body-property (remove html and returns only text). Here what I've tried so far.

```
 let headers = ["Accept": "application/vnd.dribbble.v1.text+json"]
        var manager: Manager = Manager.sharedInstance
        manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = headers

        manager.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you set 'App Transport Security Setting' with 'Allow Arbitrary Loads' into 'YES'?

Comment: @6245Htarwara yeah just did, results remain the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass `Alamofire` a  `NSMutableURLRequest` with your customized header. Check out this [issue](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1037) for a better explanation.

```
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "YOUR URL HERE")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
        request.addValue("application/vnd.dribbble.v1.text+json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        //Add paramaters (Optional)
        let param = ["foo": "bar"]
        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL
        (request, _) = encoding.encode(request, parameters: param)
        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
            //DO SOMETHING WITH YOUR RESPONSE OBJECT
        }
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters, headers: ["Accept": "application/json"]).responseJSON() { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: already tried that, alamofire returns an error stating the header type was not found. I'll try again and post the exact error soon

Comment: `"Response content type "application/json" does not match any acceptable content types: ["application/vnd.dribbble.v1.text+json"]"`

Comment: That wont work, the header need to match the header specified by the dribble api.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late but I believe might help this solution for others. In my case, I was write everything perfectly per but Alamofire doesn't post headers.

After a long try I found that issue was I don't end up my URL with '/'. So when I add this the header is posing as expected.

**Not working:**

```
http://\(baseUrl)/api/chat
```

**But this one is working:**

```
http://\(baseUrl)/api/chat/
```

**Full code:**

```
let url =  "http://\(baseUrl)/api/chat/"
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application/json",
                                    "Authorization":"Token 57bbac4b15efb531c62558eb553372a0169d9c2e"]
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers )
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.result.value as Any)
            
            if let json = response.result.value {
                if(response.response?.statusCode == 200){
                    let responseDict = json as! [String : Any]                
                    completion("Success", (response.response?.statusCode)!)
                }
                else
                {
                    completion(nil, (response.response?.statusCode)!)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                let httpError = response.result.error
                let statusCode = httpError!._code
                completion(nil, statusCode)
            }
    }
```